# React component props value issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I'm currently learning React,
I have a simple component that renders simple plain text.
I created a small component where on getting simple plain text from props, but I was surprised. when I assign a simple static value on variable then it's working fine but when I try to get that value from the props, it does not work.

here is sample snippet code.

```
let TextEditor = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    var content = "test 2";
    var content = this.props.plainText
    return {
      content: content
    };
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor
          value={this.state.content}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Advance Thanks for your clue

Comment: Where are you using `getInitialState` function? can you provide the whole code?

Comment: yes, sure I will change the above code and provide the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

getInitialState seems a little dated now. I'd recommend at least looking into the ES6 way of doing things. It's also better not to set props to state immediately in your constructor, you could update the state when the component has mounted instead. There are other ways of getting your props into your component so it's working taking a look at the react docs in a bit more detail.

As a basic ES6 example....

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { content: '' };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const { plainText } = this.props;
        this.setState({ content: plainText });
    }

    render() {
        const { content } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <Editor value={content} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using ` "react": "15.3.2",` npm package in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve the expected result :

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { content: this.props.plainText  };
    }
    render() {
        const { content } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <Editor value={content} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using ` "react": "15.3.2",` npm package in my project. may be constructor not support in this version.

Comment: I'd highly recommend upgrading to 16.9.0, if you are currently "learning react". It doesn't make sense to try to learn something on a version that is quite old.. there are many things that have / are being depreciated.